# Metadata API's LeadConvertSettings call is failing with no error message

Tags: metadata-api

I am using Metadata API (REST) to create a mapping of a custom field between Lead and Opportunity objects.

Here's my SOAP Envelope:

```
<!-- vim: set ft=xml -->
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <h:SessionHeader xmlns:h="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" 
            xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <sessionId>ACCESS_TOKEN</sessionId>
        </h:SessionHeader>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <createMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
                    <metadata xsi:type="LeadConvertSettings">
                        <objectMapping>
                            <inputObject>Lead</inputObject>
                            <mappingFields>
                                <inputField>pd_cid</inputField>
                                <outputField>pd_cid</outputField>
                            </mappingFields>
                            <outputObject>Opportunity</outputObject>
                        </objectMapping>
                    </metadata>
        </createMetadata>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The response I am getting is very vague and I have no idea what I am doing wrong:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <createMetadataResponse>
      <result>
        <fullName xsi:nil="true"/>
        <success>false</success>
      </result>
    </createMetadataResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I am getting the exact same response while trying to modify a Profile to restrict the login hours or set a login IP range... Since I only have a developer org I cannot file an official support case with Salesforce, so I used the "Give Feedback to Salesforce" feature to document this bug.

Comment: Ah, never mind. In my case I stupidly forgot to include the Profile's fullName in the SOAP API request. After fixing that, the problem went away.